# magento 1.9.x invoice PDF rendering

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

I am trying to print invoice in magento. 
I see some wired character in my invoice and my currency symbol in not visible in the invoice.

Also I see a statement (REJACKETED). What is mean by this. Do I need to worry about these ?

Please advice how do I avoid cross symbol in invoice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override magento invoice pdf model by putting in local folder and than you can apply php htmlentities function to remove unwanted characters